# Using try-catch instead of if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, try-catch, control-flow

Currently learning c#. Is there any way I could use a `try-catch` block on the code below instead of an `if` statement to validate user input?

```
string carID = txtCar.Text;
if (carID != "")
{
    car1.car = carID;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a car id e.g: ford");
}
```

Comment: You could but it would just make things harded in your case so just no need here

Comment: As a rule of thumb you shouldn't use exceptions for control flow, this is exactly the purpose of the if statement.

Comment: Not to mention try/catches are going to be far less efficient than a simple if...

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should...

Comment: Take a look @ [Are exceptions as control flow considered a serious antipattern? If so, Why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

Comment: @ChrisPickford Unless there's a good reason, e.g. a `throw new ValidationError("the thing wasn't purple enough")` you may want to catch multiple function calls higher up the stack.

Comment: To be honest, the earlier in your career you can learn to resist the urge to write "fancy" code, the better off you'll be.

Comment: If you wanted to use try/catch you would still need the if statement to see if the input is null/empty so that you can throw the exception

Comment: try/catch statements should really be used to catch exceptional behavior.  For example, if you're opening a database connection and it times out/can't connect.  For basic validation to make sure objects have a non-blank value, try/catch typically isn't the way you'd want to address it, as there's a pretty significant performance hit in doing so.  You may not notice it if it's just a one-off check, but if this was in a loop running against a hundred, a thousand, or ten thousand inputs, you certainly would notice it.

Answer (score 0):

For this case use string.IsNullorEmpty

```
string carID = txtCar.Text;
if (!string.IsNullorEmpty(carID))
{
    car1.car = carID;
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a car id e.g: ford");
}
```

Try and catch statements will slow your program so it is best to use them when necessary.  A good example of when to use a try and catch is connecting to a database, also a good time to use throw with it.  This is because the network could be down and a possible error could occur.

Comment: Your statement about avoiding try/catch here is good, since this isn't what it should be used for. Not sure what you're getting at with mentioning throw though... However, your code here doesn't really do much beyond adding null check (hence not actually answering the question). We don't know what `car` is. For all we know, assigning it any value throws an exception (probably not... just playing devil's advocate here), and OP's app will blow up.

Comment: Null check won't do much anyways, as the data is being pulled from a text field.  This will never actually return null.

Comment: Valid point on the IsNullorEmpty, but my point was when to use try and catch.  With the provided code there is no reason to use it.  The string is either empty or not.